# How to apply filter for 2 dimensional json object with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

This is my json:

```js
[{"node":
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
     'age': 1}},
    {"node":{'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 2}},
    {"node":{'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 3}}
  ];
```

This is my code:

```html
Search-title: <input type='text' ng-model="name">
    <div class='cat' ng-repeat="(key,value) in phones ">
      <ul ng-repeat="fin in value | filter:name ">
        <li><h3>{{fin.name}}</h3>
        {{fin.snippet}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I apply filter for this json object?

Answer (score 1):

please see here : http://jsbin.com/kovegi/1/edit?html,js,output CodingNinja was close just use `ng-model="searchObj.node.name"` instead `ng-model="searchObj.name"`

```
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
Search-title: <input type='text' ng-model="searchObj.node.name">
    <div class='cat' ng-repeat="(key,value) in phones  | filter:searchObj ">

  <ul ng-repeat="fin in value">
    <li><h3>{{fin.name}}</h3>
    {{fin.snippet}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: searchObj.node.name doesn't work
it works only till one nesting

Comment: @CodingNinja have you checked jsbin ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using your model in filter, make it an object and set the value in the same variable and then use it in search

```
Search-title: <input type='text' ng-model="searchObj.node">
<div class='cat' ng-repeat="(key,value) in phones | filter:searchObj">
  <ul ng-repeat="fin in value">
    <li><h3>{{fin.name}}</h3>
    {{fin.snippet}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```